# plpython get all rows on INSERT TRIGGER

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I'm trying to implement something similar to replication with python trigger procedures.

**procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo.send_payload()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
  import json, zmq

  try:
    payload = json.dumps(TD)
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    socket.connect("ipc:///tmp/feeds/0")
    socket.send(payload)
    socket.close()
  except:
    pass
$$
LANGUAGE plpython VOLATILE;
```

**trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo.my_trigger
  AFTER INSERT
  ON foo.my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo.send_payload();
```

This does work, but it's not very efficient. 
Rows are inserted in bulk and I want to reuse the socket to send all of them.
However, when I do a statement level trigger I don't have access to the rows.

I was thinking about defining a sequence which would be the last row id processed.
Then use that to grab all the data in the procedure with a `SELECT` inside the statement level trigger.
The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way of getting a sequence value without incrementing it.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two triggers. "FOR EACH ROW" would stack the rows in some temporary place (maybe [SD](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpython-sharing.html)), and "FOR EACH STATEMENT" would get data from shared place, send, and clear the shared place.

Alternatively (and I think it's better idea), you can use LISTEN/NOTIFY, as I once [described](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/13/how-to-send-mail-from-database/) in my blog.